# PHPExcel_IOFactory::load Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Tags: php

I am using PHPExcel (found here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). If i try to read more than approximately 2000 rows then it shows memory error as follows.
**Excel is around 404KB**

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32 bytes) in PHPExcelReader/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on
>   line 840

In below php code, it is failing at `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);` becuase the output shows `"Start" followed by fatal error`

**PHP Code:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
/** Include path **/
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include 'APIs/PHPExcelReader/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $inputFileName = $target;  // File to read
    //echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
    try {
echo "Start";
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
echo "End";
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:X2000', null, true, true, true)
```

Comment: @PeteR : That question was raised by me and it was totally wrong. I could not delete it.. if you can delete that. This is original question

Comment: USE CELL CACHING, AS I KEEP TELLING YOU TO DO. Asking the same question time and again will __NOT__ give you a different answer. I've answered this now for you several times, but you simply aren't listening!

Comment: @MarkBaker : can you please give me the CELL CACHING example code link ? i am actually looking for it

Comment: Section 4.2.1 of the Developer documentation (entitled "cell caching") - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md and https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/06largescale-with-cellcaching.php

Comment: @MarkBaker : is there a way to call `getCell('A'.$i) as getCell('1',$i)` ? because i want to rotate Columns as well in the loop

Comment: `getCellByColumnAndRow()`

Comment: PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_gzip; this is the only difference i see in cache example . is that correct ?

Comment: That's an example of how to use cell caching: other caching options are available, as described in the docs

Comment: @MarkBaker : If have less than 2000 records, its getting loaded now. Some time if it is around 5000 records, page load gets stopped without any errors.. when i tracked where it is stopped, page stops after reading 157th records. this is stopping at random. do you know why ?

Comment: It's probably stopping because you sill don't have enough memory available..... PHPExcel provides cell caching to help __reduce__ memory usage, it does __not__ eliminate the need for memory entirely. And the larger the number of cells you have in your spreadsheet, the more memory you'll need. The different caching options reduce the memory footprint by varying amounts (SQLite being the most memory efficient) but at a cost in speed.... I provide the mechanisms, but I can't tell you which is the best to use in your particular circumstances

Comment: cache_to_sqlite3 is the one which consumes minimal memory consumption when compared to all other options ?

Comment: Yes, because SQLite and SQLite3 store the cell data entirely within a database and use the database itself to handle indexing; all other options retain an index to file/wincache/memcache/apc/whatever in memory

Comment: I am little confused about database here. which database will it use ? becuase i dont mention any database connection over there

Comment: SQLITE is a database.... if your PHP supports SQLITE, then it's automatically available, if not, then it isn't available and trying to set caching  to SQLite will return a false

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying but values are coming as empty inside below loop..
`for($h=0;$h<$no_of_rows;$h++)
 {
  for($i=0;$i<24;$i++)
  {
      $items[$i]=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($h,$i)->getValue();
  }
}`